# Where do curl post requests "wait" when sent with & from bash

Tags: spring, curl

I send multiple `curl` post requests to a `Spring` REST API endpoint.

- First, *sequentially*:

```bash
for i in $(seq 1 10); do curl -v -F file=@Input.java localhost:8080/translator/java; done
```

- Then, *in parallel* (note the added `&` after the `curl`):

```bash
for i in $(seq 1 10); do curl -v -F file=@Input.java localhost:8080/translator/java &; done
```

The complete `Java Spring` code is [here](https://github.com/OrenGitHub/springme), but here is the important part:

- the server waits 5 seconds, then copies the file locally (for observability)

```java
    @PostMapping("/translator/java")
    public String index(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
        String s = "";
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            final String x = Integer.toString(index++);
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5); // <--- wait 5 seconds
            final Path path = Paths.get(x + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(path, bytes); // <--- create "easily observable" state
            s = "=== OK ===\n";
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        return s;
    }
```

- Sequential calls for `curl` behave *as I expect*
- Creation times of `*_Input.java` files have (approximately) 5 seconds diff:

```bash
$ ls -la -D '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' *_Input.java      
-rw-r--r--  1 oren  staff  6270 2023-12-02T07:53:43 0_Input.java # 5 sec diff, good !
-rw-r--r--  1 oren  staff  6270 2023-12-02T07:53:49 1_Input.java # 5 sec diff, good !
-rw-r--r--  1 oren  staff  6270 2023-12-02T07:53:54 2_Input.java # 5 sec diff, good !
# ... omitted ...
-rw-r--r--  1 oren  staff  6270 2023-12-02T07:54:29 9_Input.java
```

- In contrast, the "parallel" case of `curl`, I see *identical* creation times

```bash
$ ls -la -D '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' *_Input.java
-rw-r--r--  1 oren  staff  6270 2023-12-02T08:17:23 0_Input.java # no time diff
-rw-r--r--  1 oren  staff  6270 2023-12-02T08:17:23 1_Input.java # no time diff
# ... omitted ...
-rw-r--r--  1 oren  staff  6270 2023-12-02T08:17:23 9_Input.java # no time diff
```

How is this behavior possible? where do these curl requests wait? and how are they performed "simultaneously"??

Comment: I suspect that curl is creating the files immediately, rather than downloading the files and then creating them. The latter requires that curl buffer the files in memory, which could require a lot of memory if the file is big.

Comment: curl isn't creating the files at all; the server is. (@Nick) When backgrounded with `&` all 10 curls send requests at the same time (within milliseconds); the server is apparently processing them concurrently, perhaps by using multiple threads. You don't say what the server is, but Spring often uses Tomcat, which does do this.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yes, it looks like Tomcat is indeed used: `INFO 73009 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''` - I think it completely explains what I saw - thanks !